# Inequality involving an improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

> To prove: $\displaystyle \int_x^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right) \, dt < \frac{1}{x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$, $\quad x>0$

We know

$$\int_x^\infty t^{-2} \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right) \, dt \leq \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\int_x ^\infty t^{-2} \, dt = \frac{1}{x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) $$

Does the above observation lead to solution? Please give a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have obtained the right bound for a wrong integral!

$\int_x^{\infty} te^{-t^{2}/2}dt =-e^{-t^{2}/2}|_x^{\infty}=e^{-x^{2}/2}$. On $(x,\
\infty)$ note that  $t>x$ so $\int_x^{\infty} te^{-t^{2}/2}dt  >\int_x^{\infty} xe^{-t^{2}/2}dt$. Finish by pulling $x$ out of the integral.